# Fluent NHibernate no persister for entitiy class

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

I've Googled my ass off and can't seem to find the solution to my problem. 
I trying to get the demo project here: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started
to work with sql-server 2008.

I can't seem to create the sessionFactory correctly.

The code:

```
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {   
            return Fluently.Configure()
                           .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                .ConnectionString(c => c
                                    .Server("localhost")
                                    .Database("gisli")
                                    .TrustedConnection()).ShowSql())
                            .Mappings(m => { 
                                m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>(); 
                                m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Store>();
                                m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>();

                            })
                   .BuildSessionFactory();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            if(e.InnerException !=null)
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
                return null;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried to use the automapping and have not been able to make it work.

All of my entity classes are public.

Example of entity class and mapping class:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Store> StoresStockedIn { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        StoresStockedIn = new List<Store>();
    }
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Price);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.StoresStockedIn)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()
            .Table("StoreProduct");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c =>             c.Server(".").Database("gisli").TrustedConnection()))
          .Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
          .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

EDIT:
The second example is in fact the solution. I had accidentally named the project FluentNHibernate in the beginning and when I renamed the project it some how got mixed up.
Can anyone see where I´m messing it up?

sincerely
Gísli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example doesn't actually include any fluent mappings, only HBM mappings.

Your second example should work, as long as your mappings are in the same assembly as `Program`.

Comment: With the second example I get: "Could not comolie mapping document (XML Documnt)" When I view the details it says that persistent class NAMESPACE.CLASSNAME not found. Then I get could not load assembly FluentNHibernate as the inner exception.

Comment: It was a naming issue. The second example works. Thanks for the help